# Is it possible to get installed apps in ios

Tags: ios

Is it possible to get list of running/installed apps programmatically in iOS 11.if any one know the answer, please help me.I searched many sites for answer, most of them shows it is not possible.please help me

Comment: *"most of them shows it is not possible"* - and you want to hear that same answer one more time?

Comment: Apple won't allow it...if you use any private/third party libraries then just forget about App Store !!

Comment: Then How the third party  launcher apps works in iphone??????@luk2302

Answer (score 1):

Ok you cannot get all the application but you can achieve your task in different way. There is an app called Carat on App Store which lists the apps that consumes battery. And here is the GitHub link for that app

[Carat](https://github.com/carat-project/carat/tree/master/app/ios)

Maybe it will be helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AppList library to get a list of all installed apps.
It uses private frameworks so it's also jailbreak-only. Check it out at https://github.com/rpetrich/AppList.

OR

You can also read the /Applications folder. All installed applications are available in it. You need to list the directories in /Applications using NSFileManager:

NSArray *appFolderContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] directoryContentsAtPath:@"/Applications"];

Comment: The Applications folder only contains system apps, so you won’t find any information on apps downloaded from the App Store there. Store App’s binaries are stored in `/var/mobile/Containers/Bundles`, and their associated data is stored in `/var/mobile/Containers/Data`.

Comment: If you are not able to to get the list of installed app then you can also try the following piece of code. Here I have used the private framework but it's not jail broken device.#include <objc/runtime.h>
    Class LSApplicationWorkspace_class = objc_getClass("LSApplicationWorkspace");
    SEL selector=NSSelectorFromString(@"defaultWorkspace");
    NSObject* workspace = [LSApplicationWorkspace_class performSelector:selector];
    SEL selectorALL = NSSelectorFromString(@"allApplications");
    NSLog(@"apps: %@", [workspace performSelector:selectorALL]);
May this code will help you :)

Comment: But it is strictly prohibited by apple from iOS 11. @Swati Gautam

Comment: if I whitelist the 5000 apps in info.plist & use  'canopenurl'  for checking that app is installed or not. Is there any way to convince apple????