# iOS - How to avert listing of the installed apps?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, jailbreak

I have an iOS device with Undecimus installed. When I try to launch a non-jailbreak-specific game, Tapsonic TOP, it somehow reads my application list and says "Illegal program detected" and exits itself. I tried this with and without jailbreaking, and I did have tweaks to hide jailbreak detection, so it is not likely a jailbreak problem.

I've searched on StackOverflow to see how this is possible. One of the ways is to read the applications folder to retrieve a file list, and another way is to keep a whitelist of apps and use `canOpenUrl` to check the existence of each app.

[Is it possible to get installed apps in ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49125777/is-it-possible-to-get-installed-apps-in-ios/49125960)

Is it possible to modify the system so that it returns a list of only the system app directories when reading the application folder without SU permission, and always return false when checking `canOpenUrl`?

Comment: How do you know it detects jb through `canOpenUrl`? Maybe renaming `/Applications/Cydia.app` to sth else would be enough. Anyway look up `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching for a while,I have figured out what happens behind the scene.

**The Truth:**

The game detects "illegal" users by jailbreak-dection, rather than by retrieving the list of installed apps.

**Details:**

I pulled the game executable from iPhone to IDA, and searched in the function window with keyword 'jail'.The result showed that there's a method called **+[PmangPlus deviceJailbroken]**. Basically the method checked several files(including /Applications/Cydia.app,/Applications/RockApp.app,/Applications/Icy.app and so on),if either of these files exist,the method will return @"Y", otherwise @"N".

Then I wrote a substrate tweak to bypass this detection,and it worked.This works by hooking the method and returns @"N".

Hope this helps.